# USB flash drive showing "disk not formatted" error?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, formatting

When I attempt to access the files of my USB flash drive after connect it to my PC running Windows 7, it shows format error saying that it is not formatted.

Any way to fix this error?

Comment: ... by formatting it, maybe? Or is there anything on that drive?

Comment: yes, I have a batch of documents on the drive. I tried to format it, it gave me an error "the disk can't be formatted"

Comment: So the disk *was* formatted recently? Do you remember the last time it worked? I recently had a very similar experience with a card suddenly and magically becoming unformatted. It turned out that something (malware?) overwrote some of the filesystems structures with a “USBC” field. I asked it here but nobody could help. I did some tests and it turned out that fortunately, most of the filesystem data was still present.

Comment: Try a tool here. It worked for me, lexar.com - http://www.lexar.com/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Kindly open CMD window and type below command and enter.

```
format h: /q
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible causes for this kind of USB not formatted error such as the drive is severely corrupted after years' of usage or due to improper operation (strong plug-out of a pc while in data transfer), damaged FAT file system, not compatible with your current PC (if this is the first time you connect it to the computer) etc.

The first option can be - try the problematic USB drive on another computer, possibly running a different operating system, see if this will help.

Comment: nope, actually I have tried that

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your USB flash drive using this tool [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197)

Note: You may need Windows XP PC to use this tool